# Eclipse: How to restart a LaunchConfiguration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am working on a little Plugin for Eclipse to (re)start LaunchConfigurations programmatically.

I can launch a Configuration, but I want to enhance the following Code to first shut down all running Configurations with the given Name before launching.

```java
public void restartLaunchConfiguration(String configurationName) throws Exception {
    final ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();             

    for(final ILaunchConfiguration cfg : manager.getLaunchConfigurations()){
        final String cfgName = cfg.getName();

        if(!configurationName.equals(cfgName)) continue;
        cfg.launch("debug", null);  

        break;
    }
}
```

**How do I get all running Configurations?**

**How to stop a running Configuration?**

Answer (score 6):

I cannot test this but you may be able to get a list of all running ILaunchConfigurations using.

```
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunch[] runningLaunches = manager.getLaunches();
```

ILaunch then has methods you can use such as .getProcesses(). From there you can kill the process associated with the launch.